# How to unit test child validators with When() condition with FluentValidation.TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

The extension method .ShouldHaveChildValidator() in the FluentValidation.TestHelper namespace doesn't have an overload that takes the model.    How do I then test that the child validators are set up correctly when using a When() clause like in the following example?

E.g.

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public bool SomeCheckbox { get; set; }

    public ChildModel SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentModel>
{
    RuleFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
            .SetValidator(new ChildModelValidator())
            .When(m => m.SomeCheckbox);
}
```

I want to Assert that if SomeCheckbox is true, then the child validator is present, and if SomeCheckbox is false, then the child validator isn't present.

I have the following so far in the unit test:

```
ParentModelValidator validator = new ParentModelValidator();
validator.ShouldHaveChildValidator(
    m => m.SomeProperty, 
    typeof(ChildModelValidator));
```

but that doesn't take into account the .When() condition.

I notice other methods in the FluentValidation.TestHelper namespace such as .ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor() have an overload that takes the model, so it's easy to test a simple property type with a When() clause by setting up a model that satisfies the precondition.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, solution would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet of how I achieve this:

```
public class ParentModelSimpleValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentModel>
{
    public ParentModelSimpleValidator()
    {
        When(x => x.HasChild, () =>
            RuleFor(x => x.Child)
                .SetValidator(new ChildModelSimpleValidator()));
    }
}

public class ChildModelSimpleValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildModelSimpleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Whatever");
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant simplified models:

```
[Validator(typeof(ParentModelSimpleValidator))]
public class ParentModel
{
    public bool HasChild { get { return Child != null; } }
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}

[Validator(typeof(ChildModelSimpleValidator))]
public class ChildModel
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int? ChildAge { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a sample unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldValidateChildIfParentHasChild()
{
    var validator = new ParentModelSimpleValidator();

    var model = new ParentModel
    {
        ParentName = "AABBC",
        Child = new ChildModel { ChildName = string.Empty }
    };

    validator.ShouldHaveErrorMessage(model, "Whatever");
}
```

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking - you are testing if the outcome of your ParentModelSimpleValidator with a child witout name, has the outcome that the ChildValidator creates. But what if you have 20 rules in your ChildValidator? Then you would want to test your ChildValidator separate, and for the ParentValidator you would only want to test if the ChildValidator is set on the child....

Answer (score 1):

very late to the game here, but I just started using `FluentValidation` and that was my solution

```
  public class ParentValidator: AbstractValidator<ParentModel>
  {
    public ParentValidator()
    {
      // other rules here

      // use == for bool?
      When(model => model.SomeBoolProperty == false, () => RuleFor(model => model.ChildClass).SetValidator(new ChildClassValidator()));
    }
  }

  public class ChildClassValidator: AbstractValidator<ChildClass>
  {
    public ChildClassValidator()
    {
      this
        .RuleFor(model => model.SomeProperty).NotNull();
    }
  }
```

then the test is

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParentValidator_should_have_error_in_child_class_property_when_bool_is_false_on_parent()
{
  // Arrange - API does not support typical unit test
  var validator = new ParentValidator()
  var foo = new ParentModel() { SomeBoolProperty = false };
  foo.ChildClass.SomeProperty = null;

  // Act
  var result = validator.Validate(foo);

  // Assert - using FluentAssertions
  result.Errors.Should().Contain(err => err.PropertyName == "ChildClass.SomeProperty");
}
```